# PrimeFaces progressBar does not update status

Tags: primefaces

I want hide a progressbar on PrimeFaces when the process are completed. I think that isn't necessary show the progressbar while the isn't working.

The html code:

```html
<div class="container marketing" style="margin-top: 2%;">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <img class="img-circle" title="Pedir WD"
                                 width="60" height="60" border="0" style="display: block; margin: auto"/>
                            <h2 style="text-align: center !important">Arena 2</h2>
                            <center>
                                <p>Exportación del <strong>01/01/<h:outputLabel value="#{registroDriver.anoActual}"/>
                                    </strong> hasta el <h:outputLabel value="#{registroDriver.ahora}"/></p>
                                <p:commandButton value="Iniciar Petición" onclick="PF('pbAjax').start();
                                        PF('startButton2').disable();" widgetVar="startButton2" actionListener="#{registroDriver.gestionRS()}"/>
                            </center>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="margin-top: 5%">
                    <p:poll interval="2" update="pgBar"/>
                    <p:progressBar id="pgBar" widgetVar="pbAjax" ajax="true" value="#{registroDriver.progress}" labelTemplate="{value} % - #{registroDriver.estadoActual}"
                                   global="false" styleClass="animated">
                        <p:ajax event="complete" listener="#{registroDriver.onComplete()}" update="growl, linkWD" oncomplete="PF('startButton2').enable();"/>
                    </p:progressBar>
                </div>
                <h:panelGrid id="linkWD" style="margin-top: 3%; display: block;">
                    <h:outputText value="#{correo.URL_LINK}" rendered="#{registroDriver.finProceso eq true}"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
```

The java code:

```java
private Integer progress = 0;
private Integer porcentajeCompletado = 0;
private boolean controlProgreso = true;
private String estadoActual = "";
private boolean finProceso = false;

public void gestionRS() throws ClassNotFoundException, 
InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, SQLException, 
IOException, FileNotFoundException, AddressException {
System.out.println("[Conectando ...]");
System.out.println("Registrando Driver JDBC/TERADATA ...");
Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER_TERAD).newInstance();
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL_TERAD, tUser, tPass);

fCopy.fileCopy(PATH_ACCDB_LIMPIA, "accdb", PATH_DESTINO);
fCopy.fileCopy(PATH_CABECERA_MAIL, "png", PATH_DESTINO);

this.porcentajeCompletado = 5; // Estamos al  5%
estadoActual = "Conexión establecida.";
System.out.println(this.progress);
this.controlProgreso = false;
String nombreArchivoAccess = "WD_" + fechaActual.fechaActual() + ".accdb";
File archivoAccess = new File(nombreArchivoAccess);
this.porcentajeCompletado = 5; // Estamos al 10%
System.out.println(this.progress);
this.controlProgreso = false;
Database db = DatabaseBuilder.open(archivoAccess);
RSet2Access rs2Acces = new RSet2Access();

rs2Acces.resultSetToAccess(rs1, archivoAccess, db);
this.porcentajeCompletado = 10; 
System.out.println(this.progress);
this.controlProgreso = false;
estadoActual = "Confeccionada rs1";

db.close();
con.close();

System.out.println("\n[Conexión Cerrada]");
this.tamanoBase = size.tamanoArchivo(nombreArchivoAccess);
System.out.println("\nArchivo " + nombreArchivoAccess + " generado correctamente (" + this.tamanoBase + ")");

try {
    zip.zipFiles(nombreArchivoAccess);
    this.porcentajeCompletado = 40; // Sumamos los 2 procesos 
    this.controlProgreso = false;

    // Subimos el ZIP al FTP
    ftp.uploadFile(zip.getNameSaveZIP());
    this.porcentajeCompletado = 5;
    this.controlProgreso = false;
    estadoActual = "Subiendo " + zip.getNameSaveZIP() + " al servidor ...";

    File fDel = new File(nombreArchivoAccess);
    String maniobra = fDel.getAbsolutePath();

    Thread.sleep(1500);
    fd.eliminarFicheroRaiz(maniobra);
    fd.eliminarFicheroRaiz(zip.getNameSaveZIP());
    this.porcentajeCompletado = 5;
    this.controlProgreso = false;
    estadoActual = "Eliminando archivos locales ...";

    // Enviamos el mail
    mail.enviarMail(zip.getNameSaveZIP());
    fd.eliminarFicheroRaiz("cabeceraNueva.png");
    this.porcentajeCompletado = 10;
    this.controlProgreso = false;
    estadoActual = "Proceso terminado";
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finProceso = true;
onComplete();
}
```

The problem that I have are: The variable String of status that I add to % not update, only show the value in % (variable int). Is very interesting that the panelgrid on html code show when the progressbar finish (value = 100).

Thanks for all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `async="true"` on your `p:commandButton`. Without it it is "blocking" other Ajax requests since they are queued by default (`async` is `false` by default).